# Ubuntu 12.10 installer doesn't recognise Windows 8 partition on Toshiba C850 Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, 12.10, partitioning, system-installation, windows-8

I purchased a Toshiba C850 Laptop and I'm trying to install the 64 Bit version of Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8, allowing me to dual boot.

I burnt a Ubuntu 12.10 DVD, disabled Secure Boot on the Laptop and then loaded the DVD. When I selected Install Ubuntu I see that the installer hasn't recognised Windows 8 on the drive and only gives me options to erase the entire disk or to do "something else".

[image]

I've seen that it recognises other partitions but it doesn't correctly find Windows 8.

[image]

In this situation, how can I safely install Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

I shrinked one partition using the Windows Disk Management to have free and unallocated space. Booting up the installer via USB I selected "Something else" and created a 4GB swap partition where I had my freed space and the root partition for Ubuntu (in my case 13.04). However it will happen, that GRUB will not be able to boot Windows properly after the installation. This issue can be fixed by using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which will handle everything.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNCSbTyUzoM) is even a video tutorial which is basically describing what I have done though it is done in a virtual machine without UEFI but the process of the setup should be same. Moreover Boot-Repair is a one-click tool which shouldn't need any specific description.

Keep in mind, that GRUB is probably going to overwrite your Windows boot files.

**EDIT:** Considering [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2112527) it seems possible to install GRUB on the partition where you install Ubuntu, such that it doesn't mess with Windows. Using UEFI you can then choose which OS to boot which sounds pretty nice and makes it easy to delete Ubuntu and GRUB if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your partitions.  You have no free space to install Ubuntu, so the installer does not offer that option.  The only things left are the "erase disk", or "something else", meaning you fix the partitions manually for the installation.  It is recommended that you shrink a Windows partition to create the free space from within Windows, then run chkdsk a few times before running the install.  With free space, you should be offered additional choices for installation.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me when I install Ubuntu 16.04. Then I created partition using "AOMEI Partition Assistant", "and install alongside with Windows" option appeared. If you are using Rufus in order to create bootable usb, you can also try to change "create bootable disk using" to "DD image" option. Disabling fast startup in Windows 8 and secure boot in BIOS menu are other possible solutions.