# trying to dual boot Win 8 and Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uefi

I have been trying to install Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 ( 64 Bit )  on a Lenovo twist notebook.
I have now installed Windows 8 ( with UEFI, secure boot disabled ) and I am following the instructions in the post below.

[Ubuntu 12.10 installer doesn't recognise Windows 8 partition on Toshiba C850 Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280673/ubuntu-12-10-installer-doesnt-recognise-windows-8-partition-on-toshiba-c850-lap)

The problem is that Ubuntu doesn't recognise that windows is installed and if I ignore this, and proceed by selecting 'other' and go on to partition the free space on the hard disk for Ubuntu, I lose the Windows boot when it's completed.
Using Boot Repair doesn't work either so I have to clear it all off using GParted and start over by installing Windows 8 again.
What do I have to do to get the Windows install recognised and to install Ubuntu ?
Thanks,

Comment: Wait, do you mean no UEFI firmware on your notebook?

Comment: I mean that I have disabled UEFI in the Bios.

Comment: So your notebook has UEFI and secure boot is disabled...

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Just to confirm. UEFI AND Legacy switch is enabled and secure boot is disabled.

Comment: If you've disabled EFI in the firmware (you don't have a BIOS), then chances are you've got Ubuntu installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and Windows installed in EFI mode. This will lead to an ability to boot one OS or the other, but switching between them will be tricky. It's best to install both OSes in the ***same boot mode*** (EFI or BIOS).